# Odoo: How to retrieve values from another model?

Tags: php, odoo-10

I have a model called 'hr.applicant'. Under this model, I've created a field called 'x_contract_type' which a selection field type and the selection options contain the following: [('test', 'TEST'), ('test2','TEST2')]
I have another model called 'hr.employee'. What I'm trying to do is: when I select 'TEST' under 'Contract Type' in my 'hr.applicant' model, I would like to have that field appear under my 'hr.employee' model under the same field name 'Contract Type'. Basically, the end goal is to have fields in the 'hr.applicant' model appear in the 'hr.employee' model once they have been selected or have gone through the recruitment process; this would include not only fields but the documents associated with the individual while they are still considered an applicant.

I've been searching around and just found out about dependencies as I'm fairly new to Odoo. I tried playing around with the Advanced Properties primarily the 'Dependencies' and 'Compute' fields since I've read a few posts that were similar to my inquiry but not quite. I keep getting this error when trying to save my input on the 'Dependencies' field:

"Error while validating constraint

Unknown field u'hr' in dependency u'hr.applicant.x_contract_type"

For sure I'm missing something but I can't seem to understand it. Perhaps someone with more experience with Odoo can point me to the right direction or advise? Thank you

I've tried playing around with fields under the Database Structure for both models.

for record in self:
    record['x_contract_type'] = record.hr.applicant.x_contract_type